# Problem with the procedure for changing data in a specific table

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm just starting my adventure in mysql. At the time of creating the procedure for changing the quantity in the table. I get this error

> #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok '' in line 5

And this is my procedure

```sql
Create procedure towar_add (IDStatusu Int, tIlosc Int)
begin
Update towar
set Ilosc = Ilosc + tIlosc
where ID = IDStatusu;
END
```

I've always created everything in SQL and MySQL is new to me

Comment: I don't see "obok" here. Is that the exact error?

Comment: This is likely an issue with not changing the `DELIMITER`.

Comment: Looks like delimiter reassigning lost. In your particular case - simply remove `begin` and `END` keywords.